# Same confusion matrix depiste hyperparameter tuning using TrainImageClassifier in OTB

Tags: classification, machine-learning, otb-applications

I am trying to run a land use land cover classification using TrainImageClassifier in OTB. Here are the settings I used :
[image]

[image]

The problem is that no matter how much I tweak the hyperparameters of any of the available algorithms I end up with the same final confusion matrix and scores:

[image: c]

Comment: You do not have a very good model, lots of cross classification error into class 10. I imagine that the parameter tuning is just not making a wit of difference across models. I would take a step back an look at the spectral separability of your classes int your training data. Although, with different parameters or algorithms I would not expect the CM to be identical. Perhaps the CM was written out and not overwritten. Check to see if it exists on disk and delete it or restart the software.

Comment: What about the settings in OTB are they correct ?, And yes I delete the cm after each run.

Comment: I cannot see the entire windows but, mostly looks ok. In the command line version there is an argument `-cleanup true` that forces clean up of temporary files. There may be a check box somewhere in the GUI that does the same.

Comment: Yeah it is already set to 'on'.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding double quotes " " around the filenames in QGIS.

It seems that the QGIS plugin does not like the spaces in the paths.